# Javascript Countdown to show/hide on specified days & hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I've been trying to take and work with some code that I can get partially working, I want a countdown that we can set an end time it counts down to (obvious is obvious out of the way), we also want to set it to show at only certain times of the day and only certain days of the week.

I've managed to get the below working so we can set a time of the day to show but I can't get it to work so it only shows on the certain specified days. Can anyone help please?

```js
var countdownMessage = "This ends in";
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
var countdownEnd = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 12, 59); // countdownEnd 0000 hrs

//////////////////////////* Countdown *///////////////////////////////
function getSeconds() {
  var ft = countdownEnd.getTime() + 86400000; // add one day
  var diff = ft - time;
  diff = parseInt(diff / 1000);
  if (diff > 86400) {
    diff = diff - 86400
  }
  startTimer(diff);
}

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs) {
  timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
  ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
  tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
  var secs = timeInSecs;
  if (secs > 0) {
    timeInSecs--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
    //getSeconds();  // and start again if required
  }

  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;
  var result = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + " hours " + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + " minutes " + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs + " seconds";
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (countdownMessage) + " " + result;
}


///////////////* Display at certain time of the day *//////////////////

//gets the current time. 
var d = new Date();
if (d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 15) {
  $("#countdown").show();
} else {
  $("#countdown").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="getSeconds()">

  <span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>

</body>
```

[EDIT]

Just to add to this I tried changing part of the script to this but it didn't work:

```
$(function() {
$("#countdown").datepicker(
    { beforeShowDay: function(day) {
        var day = day.getDay();
        if (day == 1 || day == 2) {
            //gets the current time. 
            var d = new Date();
            if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 10 ){
                $("#countdown").show();
            }
            else {  
                 $("#countdown").hide();
            }
        } else {
            $("#countdown").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: please define "didn't work". You get an error message, or it doesn't work the way you expected? Give an example.

Comment: Hi, it just ignores my code, so I set the start and end time and it hides when it's outside of these times, however when I added the code to specify the days of the week it does nothing different no matter what start and end date I adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you did is all good except the `setInterval` part where you are passing the string value as `setInterval("tick()", 1000)` instead of a function reference as `setInterval(tick, 1000)`

Also, I have updated the code as below to check the specific day along with specific hours which you had,

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();

if (day == 0 || day == 6) {
  if (d.getHours() >= 0 && d.getHours() <= 8) {
    $("#countdown").show();
  } else {
    $("#countdown").hide();
  }
}
```

You can give a try below,

```js
var countdownMessage = "This ends in";
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
var countdownEnd = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 12, 59); // countdownEnd 0000 hrs

//////////////////////////* Countdown *///////////////////////////////
function getSeconds() {
  var ft = countdownEnd.getTime() + 86400000; // add one day
  var diff = ft - time;
  diff = parseInt(diff / 1000);
  if (diff > 86400) {
    diff = diff - 86400
  }
  startTimer(diff);
}

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs) {
  timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
  ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
  var secs = timeInSecs;
  if (secs > 0) {
    timeInSecs--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
    //getSeconds();  // and start again if required
  }

  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;
  var result = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + " hours " + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + " minutes " + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs + " seconds";
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (countdownMessage) + " " + result;
}

$("#countdown").hide();

///////////////* Display at certain time of the day *//////////////////

//gets the current time. 
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();

if (day == 0 || day == 6) {
  if (d.getHours() >= 0 && d.getHours() <= 8) {
    $("#countdown").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="getSeconds()">

  <span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry I implemented this and was playing with it on Friday before the weekend but it wouldn't seem to work, it doesn't even work for me when I run the snippet so I don't know whats going on. When I even try copy and pasting your whole code in it shows the timer after 8am which outside of the codes parameters straight away and if I adjust the days to 2 || 3 it was still showing the countdown and not hiding as if it's ignoring the whole if else statements. Is there any further help please? Thanks

Comment: When you copy paste my code, you should change the day which I mentioned at `if (day == 0 || day == 6)` and also you should change the time  at `if (d.getHours() >= 0 && d.getHours() <= 8) {`. FYI, `days start at `0 to 6` where `0` is `Sunday`

Comment: Sorry I mustn't have been very clear, so I took your code on Friday (day 5) at about 2pm so I changed the code to: if (day == 2 || day == 3)   AND THEN ALSO CHANGED:   if (d.getHours() >= 18 && d.getHours() <= 19) which should have hid the countdown; as it should only shown the countdown between 6pm Tuesday & 7pm Tuesday; but it didn't. I have just tried the same code again now with the same results. I really want to give you the reputation and answer marks but it's just not working for me, is it working for yourself? Thanks

Comment: Okay let me check with the same date and time.

Comment: I found the issue, There was a hide part for hours and not for the day. I fixed it and changed the code. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks for your constant updates I really appreciate it, I thought I had it right however what am I doing wrong, in this jsfiddle withyour updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/jb4aqq4c/2/ it should be showing the countdown as it's within the select day/time frame but it's not showing anything are you able to quickly update this jsfiddle so I can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Great I will and can you confirm the above code is working as you expected and I will fix your fiddle

Comment: Okay, I have updated your fiddle and the latest url is https://jsfiddle.net/jb4aqq4c/3/. Nothing wrong with the code. Its the way how the `jsfiddle` is calling all the javascript code. They have enclosed all the scripts in `window.onload = function() { // all the code here }`. As your body tag has `onload=getSeconds()` method, it can't find the `getSeconds` method as it's enclosed inside another function and returns error. I removed the `onload=getSeconds()` from the `body` tag and added a line `getSeconds()` at the bottom. But this should be fine when you check this in your machine.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it really I want this code to work, confirmed above code :)

Comment: Your a real star and asset to the community Aruna, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Is the mix of jquery and javascript intentional? I notice you reference the countdown on its own using jquery, but then use `document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML` to set the value.